# Hive Create Table error

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm attempting to create a Hive table using JSONSerde with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
device_uuid string,
uuid string,
custom struct<
    "Vendor ID":int,
    "Customer ID":int>,
platform string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

The problem I'm encountering when I try and create the table is the following:

```
Error occurred executing hive query: OK converting to local hdfs://dpcl01:820/user/hive/aux_jars/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar Added /tmp/523576-5d62-4fff-b737-813aca807eee_resources/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar to class path Added resource: /tmp/52356576-5d62-4fff-b737-813aca807eee_resources/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar FAILED: ParseException line 8:2 cannot recognize input near '"Vendor ID"' ':' 'int' in column specification
```

It's obvious that this error is due to the space in the column name but the raw data comes in that form and I don't want to perform a pre-processing step to remove spaces.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to sustain a pre-processing stage (I'm assuming that loading up the raw text in a staging table and then transforming it counts as pre-processing in your context), the most straightforward option to me would be to extend the SerDe to perform that replacement of the spaces to something like underscores during deserialization in order to match your Hive column/struct field name definitions.  From what I can see of the source code (I assume you're using [this SerDe](https://github.com/sheetaldolas/Hive-JSON-Serde)), the `put` method of the `JSONObject` object class could be overridden so that all instances of whitespace in the `key` parameter are converted prior to insertion into the underlying map object.

If you **are** willing to entertain the approach using the staging table, you could always load up your raw text and use `get_json_object` to extract what you need, since spaces are perfectly fine in JSON paths for Hive.  For example:

```
get_json_object(raw_text, "$.Vendor ID")
```

Comment: Are you saying to use get_json_object instead of the Serde? I'm not comfortable with get_json_object but would the query not be:                      `select get_json_object(raw_text, "$.custom.Vendor ID") as vendor_id`

Comment: @LouisRyan I think you've got the gist of it.  This way your query can be the translation layer between the field names in the JSON and the Hive column names.

Comment: I know this is a far ask but I have no experience in Java and don't understand how to override methods. Would you be able to provide assistance with this process?